# Redirect subdomain and path to main domain with same path

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, wildcard-subdomain

I have recently stopped using a subdomain for my blog, i need to forward all links that use that domain to the same link path but on my main domain.

Example being:

- blog.example.com/blog/sales/blog-title

needs to redirect to :

- www.example.com/blog/sales/blog-title

I can redirect the subdomain itself so

-blog.example.com/

goes to

- www.example.com/blog

but as soon as I try to redirect a page it doesn't redirect and doesn't load. Can anyone shed some light on it? I currently have this in my htaccess for my main redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I have other subdomain redirects going on but none wildcard redirect.

Comment: Where are you using these rules? in root/blog/.htaccess?

Comment: no this is in the root of my wordpress site, blog is included in the page path it isn't a folder

Comment: Are you getting a 404 error?

Comment: Yes if i try to visit a link with blog.example.com/blog/example-name it keeps the URL the same and shows me a 404 error page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you want to redirect from

```
blog.example.com/blog/sales/blog-title
```

to

```
www.example.com/blog/sales/blog-title
```

But in your rule, you insert another subdirectory `blog` in the substitution part, which gives

```
www.example.com/blog/blog/sales/blog-title
```

instead, and an error 404 as a result.

To redirect from one domain to another with the exact same request path, use

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

---

When it works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301`. Never test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).